# Javascript localStorage.getitem does not work on other tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have saved some user data on one page using `localStorage.setItem`. I am now trying to reopen the data in another tab, but it will not work. Code sample below:

popup.js

```
    localStorage.setItem("item", document.getElementById('item').value);
    localStorage.setItem("color", document.getElementById('color').value);
    alert(localStorage.getItem("item"))
    // "Test"
```

Search.js

```
var kws = localStorage.getItem("item");
var color = localStorage.getItem("color");
alert(kws)
// "null"
```

LocalStorage is supposed to work on a browser, so calling it from a different tab should not matter.

Comment: What are the urls of each tab?

Comment: Are both scripts in the same domain?

Comment: @Barmar I'm building a Chrome Extension so I am not sure

Comment: @Evert I am building a Chrome Extension so the extension has no URL

Comment: Each domain has its own local storage. You should probably be using `chrome.storage` in an extension.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I have tried to use chrome storage and I have run into another issue.

popup.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'item': document.getElementById('item').value})
```

search.js


```
var keywords;
chrome.storage.sync.get("kws", function(items){keywords = items.kws;});
alert(keywords)
// undefined
```

Why can't I get the data from Chrome storage?

Comment: @ArthurXu because chrome API is asynchronous it should be used inside the callback, see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)